# html - having subscript and superscript one on top of another

Tags: html, css

With html (or css) is there a way to have a subscript and superscript in the same location? I tried this

```
<sup>16</sup><sub>16.00</sub>O
```

but this will make the superscript 16 to the left of the subscript 16.00, is there a way to make the subscript and superscript one on top of another?

Note that I am not using CSS3.

Note that I tried making this my CSS

```
.container {}

.sup { 
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
}

.sub {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: -0.5em;
}
```

with this as the html

```
<span class='sup'>3</span><span class='sub'>4</span>
```

which works but it depends on the length of the digits. This won't look right

```
<span class='sup'>16</span><span class='sub'>16.000</span>
```

since the superscript has 2 digits while the subscript has 6 digits. Is there a way to make them right aligned? I tried doing

```
.container {
   text-align: right;
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: How large of a square do you want to replicate this in?  100x100?

Comment: The picture does not show subscripts and superscripts. Rather, a two-dimensional setup. There are various approaches to implementing it (a table is probably the most robust approach), but the code in the question doesn’t try to do that. You should specify what you are really asking for. This should include a description of the intended context of the presentation.

Answer (score 5):

With a little bit of structuring using div's and floats I was able to replicate the image using `<sub>` and `<sup>` elements.  My example fits all elements into a 100px by 100px square.  If that box needs to be smaller or can be large then some minute adjustments will be needed obviously.

This is all CSS2 spec also, no CSS3 was used so no compatibility issues.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8Zyc/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="superscripts">
        <sup class="sup-left">16</sup>
        <sup class="sup-right">8</sup>
    </div>
    <div class="element"><abbr>O</abbr><br /> Oxygen</div>
    <div class="subscripts">
        <sub class="sub-left">16.00</sub>
        <sub class="sub-right">(6)</sub>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.element {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    height: 60px;
}

.element abbr {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.superscripts,
.subscripts {
    height: 18px;
}


.superscripts .sup-left {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.superscripts .sup-right {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
.subscripts .sub-left {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 0 2px 2px;
}

.subscripts .sub-right {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding: 4px 2px 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I made sure to use the proper elements for the type of text that is there, semantically Google should like this compared to using a bunch of Spans.

Comment: @Michael Normally, I'd agree, except in this case, the corners of the element box are not really superscripts or subscripts of the main element, just specific layout formatting. Regardless, either one works. I just prefer `em` because it allows everything to zoom instead of only the text.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be a little less complicated and more flexible by using absolute positioning and `em` instead of `px`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuE5G/1/).

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="edge">
    <span class="top left">16</span>
    <span class="top right">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <abbr>O</abbr>
    <div>Oxygen<div>
  </div>
  <div class="edge">
    <span class="bottom left">16.00</span>
    <span class="bottom right">(6)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 7em;
  width: 7em;
  border: .2em solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

abbr {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.edge span {
  position: absolute;
  padding: .4em;
}

.top    { top: 0; }
.bottom { bottom: 0; }
.right  { right: 0; }
.left   { left: 0; }
```